# Securing GAE Rest API

Tags: security, google-app-engine, rest

I would like to know how to secure a REST API on a Google App Engine. I did a research and understood several concepts around the oauth and spring security.

But still i can't see a clear method which illustrates the method to implement with advantages and disadvantages. If some one can make it organized and brief on the methodology, It will be of great help for newbies.

1. How HTTPS will help me prevent rest calls from applications or users that are not mine.
2. Even with oauth, if a user logs in and does rogue REST requests how would i prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial.  Once you have an OAuth token and you can identify the user, just return an error instead of actual data on a 'rogue' REST request.

Comment: How do i identify that the request is rogue request. If the user is trying to access my application then it is not rogue. But if he has constructed the URL in the browser or trying to hit that url from his own web application that it is rogue. This will result in my quota being used for others purpose.

Does GAE provide any option where the request will be served only from the particular applications client or it responds to any application or url request.